# Получение среднего n-ых элементов списка и особое преобразование

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, список

(заголовок только для факта)
хватит минусить, если не можете понять

В общем есть 2 списка одинаковой длины:

```
list-1 = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list-1v2 = [-4.3,3.5,2.9,9.6,-2.4,1.9,6.4,7.1,-7.2,0.2]  
list-2 =   [   5,  1,  2,  4,   5,  1,  3,  5,   3,  1]
```

1-ый со всякими числами, 2-ой имеет одинаковые значения.
Upd: добавил более показательный список (list-1v2), остальные примеры основаны на list-1 и list-2
(list-1 содержит конечное количество уникальных рациональных чисел, не важно что означающих; list-2 содержит конечное количество положительных рациональных чисел, также не важно что означающих. Для простоты примера их по 10 неотрицательных в диапазоне от 0 до 10. Собственно, для понимания сути вопроса всё касаемо содержимого их было сообщено за скобками, а это даже лишнее)

Необходимо найти средние элементов 1-го списка, которые имеют одно и тоже значение во втором на соотв. позициях.

Т.е. одно среднее от 0,4,7 (=3.66...), другое от 1,5,9 (=5), третье от 6,8 (=7).

И затем так преобразовать пару списков, чтобы сохранилось позиционирование усреднённого значения из 1-го списка относительно значения, на основании которого производилось усреднение, из 2-го списка.

Т.е. ожидаемые результаты (любой из них):

```
a) list-1 = [3.66, 5, 2, 3, 7]
   list-2 = [   5, 1, 2, 4, 3]
   (тут я предполагал замену первого встречного)

b) list-1 = [2, 3, 3.66, 5, 7]
   list-2 = [2, 4,    5, 1, 3]
   (а тут конечную вставку)
```

или ещё любые комбинации, с сохранением вертикального соответствия 2-2, 3-4, 5-1, 7-3, 3.66-5, но желательней, что бы оба были отсортированы по 1-му, т.е. как раз как в b (для лучшего понимания добавил пробелов).

Пробовал некоторым способом, в котором встал в тупик при преобразовании списков, а т.к. хотелось бы получить полноценное решение по лучше, вопрос без неудачного кода. И прошу воздержаться от выклянчивания его.

Upd: Суть вопроса: Какой код позволит получить

усредняющим "сжатием" (сжатие т.к. длина списков уменьшается) тех элементов 1-го списка, которые имеют "под собой" (во 2-ом списке) одно и тоже число (например 5 (из 2-го) для 0,4,9 (из 1-го)

из начальной пары списков конечную.

улучшенное мной решение MBo здесь:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

def AvgComprss(l1,l2):
    D = defaultdict(list)
    for i, v in enumerate(l1):
        D[v].append(l2[i])
    D = [[n, mean(D[n])] for n in D]
    return map(list, zip(*sorted(D)))

list-1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
list-2 = [5,1,2,4,5,1,3,5,3,1]
list-2, list-1 = AvgComprss(list-2, list-1)
print(list-1)
print(list-2)

Выводит:
[5, 2, 7, 3, 3.6666666666666665]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Это потенциально лучшее исполнение решения задачи.

Comment: ничего не понял, но очень интересно. А вы могли бы перефразировать свой вопрос так чтобы стала понятна чуть вопроса. Попробуйте перечитать свой вопрос незамыленным взглядом

Comment: @Zhihar Примеры, на мой взгляд, исчерпывают себя, не знаю таких слов какими бы можно было бы описать суть вопроса ясней. Я его полтора часа составлял.

Comment: `1-ый со всякими числами, 2-ой имеет одинаковые значения.` да уже это предложение заставляет задуматься, особенно когда смотришь еще и на пример этих двух списков выше - т.е. вы реально считаете что тут все понятно?

Comment: @Zhihar Да, я честно не понимаю, как можно отвечать не умея читать.

Comment: ну так объясните мне эту вашу первую строчку, ведь над ней вы тоже наверное долго думали, что значит "одинаковые значения"?

Comment: @Zhihar Это значит что len(set(list-2))<len(list-2). Ясней? Или может быть так: в данном примере 2-ой список содержит несколько пятёрок, несколько троек, несколько единиц, т.е. содержит одинаковые значения (пятёрки, тройки, единицы). Или так: list-2 не является уникальным списком, т.е. содержит дубликаты. Надеюсь достаточно.

Comment: мда, ужас :) честно скажу - никогда бы не понял что, `повторяющиеся значения` как-то более по-русски будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```
la = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
lb = [5,1,2,4,5,1,3,5,3,1]
dic = dict()
for i in range(len(lb)):
    if lb[i] in dic:
        dic[lb[i]].append(la[i])
    else:
        dic[lb[i]] = [la[i]]
lc = []
for x in dic:
    ls = dic[x]
    m = sum(ls) / len(ls)
    lc.append((m, x))
lc.sort()
aa, bb = map(list, zip(*lc))
print(aa)
print(bb)

 >>>>
[2.0, 3.0, 3.6666666666666665, 5.0, 7.0]
[2, 4, 5, 1, 3]
```

Comment: `aa, bb = zip(*lc)` только там будет кортеж, а не список, но это легко исправить

Comment: @Danis Да, именно, кортеж кортежей получался,

Comment: `map(list, zip(*lc))`

Comment: @Danis  О, спасибо!

Comment: Место спасибо лучше принят отв... ой. Лучше проголосуйте за мой ответ :)

Comment: @Danis Он пока не тот ответ даёт. Данные собираются, но не сортируются?

Comment: я проверял и он выводит такое же результат который требует автор

Comment: @Danis А, я забыл, что он два варианта указал, т.к. сразу опиралcя на `желательней, что бы оба были отсортированы по 1-му,`

Comment: @Paw -'-el-'- Cow Код вроде бы по шагам выполняет то, что описано. Где эта проверочная выборка?

Comment: @MBo Да, верно, перепутал списки, пока это лучший ответ хотя в эффективности сомневаюсь. Занимаюсь переписыванием вашего ответа, позже добавлю, но и на том Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
def f(arr1, arr2):
    res1, res2 = [], []
    
    for el in sorted(set(arr2), key=arr2.index):
        arr = [i for i in range(len(arr2)) if arr2[i] == el]
        res1.append(sum(arr) / len(arr))
        res2.append(el)
        
    return res1, res2
```

Comment: Благодарю за попытку, похоже я своим первым списком попутал вас поэтому добавил list-1v2, полагаю поэтому так был написан `arr`, из-за этого код не даёт желаемое.